# values not passing from servlet to database,

Tags: java, hibernate, servlets

i was trying to send values which were taken from html page ,i called DAO class with the values passed in its object...but following errror was thrown
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [abc] in context with path [/testservlet1] threw exception [Servlet executio`enter code here`n threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry

//
public class trail4 extends HttpServlet{

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse  resp) throws IOException
{   
   resp.setContentType("Text/html");
    int age= Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("age"));//got age  from html page
    //BigInteger num=(req.getParameter("num"); //got fone number from html page
    //String num=req.getParameter("num");
    long num=Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("num")); //got number from html page
    String name=req.getParameter("name");//got name
   PrintWriter out =resp.getWriter();
    
    out.println("your no="+num);
    out.println("<br>");
    out.println("your age "+age);
    out.println("<br>");
    out.println("your name "+name);
    out.println("<br>");
    
  trail2 obj1=new trail2(age,name);//make object of trail2 class which has the code of  hibernate
  //passed age and name,dint pass the number in this run      
        boolean b=obj1.detailsaved(obj1);//called detail saved method of trail 2 class
  //and passed obj1
        if(b==true)
         {
           out.println("Employee details sucessfully saved <br>");
            
         }
          
         else
         {
             out.println("Employee details not Saved.<br>"); 
         }
         out.println(" <br>");
         out.close();
                   
}
```

====================================================================================================

public class trail2 {

```
public trail2(int age, String name) //made constructor to initialise values
{
}

public boolean detailsaved(trail2 obj1)
```

{

```
    boolean flag=true;
      StandardServiceRegistry ssr = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").build();  
      Metadata meta = new MetadataSources(ssr).getMetadataBuilder().build();  
      SessionFactory factory=meta.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();
      Session session=factory.openSession();           
      org.hibernate.Transaction t=session.beginTransaction();  
      session.save(obj1);
      t.commit();
System.out.println(" details saved check database...);
return flag;      
}
```

}

Comment: `ClassNotFoundException` occurs when your classpath is incomplete. First, make sure your code is compiling without errors (e.g.: your last print is missing a closing quote), then include more details about your setup (are you using Maven? How are you referencing Hibernate classes?)

Answer (score 0):

The error is:

```
ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry
```

This most likely means that Hibernate is not on the classpath of your web server.

Typically you need to include it in the libraries of your `.war` or `.ear` deployment, or add it as a base module of your web server.